# Flutter Widget Overflow Parent (Tabbar Oversized item)

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to have a tab bar that looks like this:

[image: TabBar result]

Note the center "My ID" button.

So here is my main problem: 
 Obviously I need a `SafeArea` to deal with irregular shaped screens, which itself need to be embedded in a Container so I can give the bar its background color. But, by doing this, how can I create the "oversized" button at the center?

Comment: it should be at the bottom of page or top?

Comment: @Eugene bottom.

Answer (score 0):

After spending several hours banging my head against the wall, found a not so elegant solution. (Hey, but it works)

Here's a picture of the result.

[image: App Running]

So the way I made it work is actually by having two layers.

On the base of the widget tree is a `Stack` which contains everything that is currently seen on this page.

The actual bar widget has the text and icons, (the My ID part has only text no icon, but a placeholder `SizedBox` is used in place of the icon otherwise would be there)

By using the stack, I am able lay the round icon on top of the entire bar much like a `FloatingActionButton`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a floating action button instead of making an oversized button regarding its area. Or you can directly create an overlay over your scaffold and locate it wherever you want. I believe The best practice would be a floating action button.